# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor por defecto?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo una función con un parámetro rest, y 2 parámetros más:

```js
function some(a,b,...rest){
 var sumaTotal = 0;
 if(b == undefined) {
 b = 5;
  ...rest = arguments[1];
 }
 Array.from(...rest).forEach(e => {
  sumaTotal += e;
 });
 return sumaTotal + a + b;
}
var arrayParametro = [4,3,3];
console.log(some(10,4,arrayParametro));
```

Esa función **suma los parámetros solamente**, el **problema** es el siguiente:

Si la función no recibe el parámetro `'b'` , hago un `if` que hara que `b = 5` y que el parametro rest `...rest` , **empieze** desde `arguments[1]` , **ya que en** `arguments[2]` **no habría nada**, pero me lanza errores, ¿Por qué?

Comment: como lo estás intentando mandar cuando te  marca el error?

Comment: `pero me lanza errores` = ¿cuáles son los errores?

Comment: Solo basta con sacar el comentario del código

Answer (score 0):

Los `...` solo se utilizan en la definición del parámetro, para usarlo se hace de forma común, adicionalmente no estas recorriendo los  `array` que pasas por parametro ya que solo estas recorriendo el `array rest`

El parámetro `rest` siempre es un arreglo, por lo que no es necesario crear un arreglo a partir de este. En el `foreach`, `e` representa cada parámetro adicional que se envía, si el parámetro es un arreglo, debería recorrerse los elementos de este para poder sumarlos, sino se hace de esta forma, `js` concatenara un `string` separado por comas a la variable `sumaTotal`, provocando que esta ya no sea numérica, y continué concatenando elementos. Sino simplemente la suma a `sumaTotal`

```js
function some(a, b, ...rest) {
  var sumaTotal = 0;
  if (typeof b != "number") {
    rest = arguments[1];
    b=5;
  }
  rest.forEach(e => {
    if (Array.isArray(e))
      e.forEach(i => {
        sumaTotal += i;
      });
    else
      sumaTotal += e;
  });  
  return sumaTotal + a + b;
}
var arrayParametro = [4, 3, 3];
console.log(some(10, 5, arrayParametro));
console.log(some(10, arrayParametro));
```

Comment: Que haces después de Array.isArray ? porque otro forEach?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian amplié la respuesta para que quede mas clara